# Python Selenium dummy website generation error after specifying profile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, computer-forensics

Im Working on a research project in Digital Browser forensics and I'm trying to generate a bunch of dummy data using selenium. Got my script working however I want it to run on my default profile. I have it opening the window and using my profile however I get this error message:

My sourcecode is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\webdata.py", line 16, in <module>
    "Chrome": webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options),
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65E8952A2+57122]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E80EA92]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E6DE3AB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E706B1F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E702FE1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E73EA4F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E73E5B0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E736DB3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E70D2B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E70E494]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65EB3EF82+2849794]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65EB91D24+3189156]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65EB8ACAF+3160367]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65E926D06+653702]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E81A208]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E8162C4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E8163F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65E8067A3]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFDC2CD7344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFDC2FC26B1+33]
```

Below is my sourcecode some help would be really appreciate here at my wits end!! Cheers all

```
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# List of websites to visit
websites = ["https://www.example.com/", "http://birds.example.com/?bird=airplane&behavior=birth", "https://www.example.com/", "https://www.example.com/", "http://www.example.net/box"]
# Define the web browsers and their respective drivers
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

#chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir='r'C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
browsers = {

    "Chrome": webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options),
    #"Firefox": webdriver.Firefox(),
    #"Brave": webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/brave/driver"),
    # "Edge": webdriver.Edge(executable_path="/path/to/edge/driver")
}

# Number of random visits
num_visits = 5

# Function to simulate page visits
def simulate_web_traffic(browser_name):
    browser = browsers[browser_name]
    browser.get(random.choice(websites))
    
    try:
        cookie_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Accept cookies;')]")  # Modify with actual element ID
        cookie_button.click()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 8))  # Simulate user interaction time

# Simulate web traffic for each browser
for browser_name in browsers.keys():
    print(f"Simulating web traffic for {browser_name}:")
    for _ in range(num_visits):
        simulate_web_traffic(browser_name)
    browsers[browser_name].quit()
```

Tried specifying the profile path which I have now got working however I cant get past the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the profile name like below. If you want the default profile, it should be `..\User Data\Default`. If the profile name is Profile 1, then it should be `..\User Data\Profile 1`

```
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1")
```

Comment: Turns out the issue stemmed from me not adding https://www. before all my websites in the array. Thanks for the support!